# is it possible to create a moving object in front of the camera background?

Tags: android, drawable, android-camera

what I wanna make is just a simple app that there will be some drawable image that moving with a camera as the background. at first I thought I can use framelayout with 2 surface view and after try and search I find it useless. So I though to combine the camera view with the moving drawable but I can't find how to combine and I don't know if it is possible or not. so I just wanna know that is there is a way to make it?